# Threejs position mesh to 0,0,0

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to position a simple cube at 0,0,0.

When I position a box in 0,0,0 I get this result:
[image]

But it is not correct. This is what I need to achieve:
[image]

My code is very very simple:

```
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1));
cube.position.x = 0;
cube.position.z = 0;
cube.position.y = 0;
cube.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 'green' });
this.scene.add(cube);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of the mesh is (0, 0, 0), because [`BoxGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry) creates the mesh with a minimum of *(-width/2, -height/2, -depth/2)* and a maximum of *(width/2, height/2, depth/2)*. The size of your cube is *(1, 1, 1)*. So the minimum of the cube is *(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)* and you have to move the cube by (0.5, 0.5, 0.5):

```js
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1));
cube.position.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Instead of changing the position of the mesh, you can also [`translate`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.translate) the geometry:

```js
const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1).translate(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry);
```

A more general approach is to translate the mesh by the minimum of its bounding box:

```js
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);

// this works for any geometry
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
geometry.translate(
    -geometry.boundingBox.min.x,
    -geometry.boundingBox.min.y,
    -geometry.boundingBox.min.z);
```

Comment: This is the normal behaviour? So threejs calculates the center of the object also for complicated shapes?

Comment: @user3471528 ???? `BoxGeometry` creates the mesh in that way. It creates a cube with the minimum of (-width/2, -height/2, -depth/2) and a maximum of (width/2, height/2, depth/2). What is a complicate shape? Of course the center of a `SphereGeometry` is (0, 0, 0), too. But if you load a mesh (GLB/GLTF/OBJ...), threejs doesn't change the vertices of the mesh. All depends on how the mesh is constructed.

Comment: @user3471528 A more general approach is to translate the mesh by the negative minimum of its bounding box. I added that approach to the answer.